# masonry images loaded not working

Tags: jquery-masonry

Dear community im using the masonry script on this site: http://www.hoeckernetworks.impulsfaktor.abcde.biz/
I was searching for an option to fix the picture loading problem and i found imagesLoaded. I try to get it to work, but it wont do its job. I am not a great javascript programmer and tryed it with the example code. Maybe someone has a hint for me. Just to inform: i use masonry working with html. If its needed i can send my source but i think one can see it on the site.

regards an already thanks for any help

Comment: post your code please